Meaning of "She'd give a dog a bone"
In a movie Wayne's World 2, at the beginning when Wayne say to the camera what was happening with his life since first Wayne's World. He talks about his girlfriend Cassandra and he says:

What a babe. She'd give a dog a bone.

What does it mean?
I was searching and found this question:
An idiom or a saying like "give a dog a bone" or "throw someone a crumb". But it looks like the explanation doesn't make sense in the context of the movie. Note that Mike Myers (the main actor) is from Canada, so maybe this is Canadian idiom or a slang phrase.

If dawg is slang for a sly guy, her allure would tend to be stimulating.

It's probably just intended as something that sounds funny while being capable of having several meanings. A joke.

Urban dictionary uses exactly your example from Wayne's world and explains:

If a woman can "Give a dog a bone", it is to be taken as a compliment that even animals find her attractive. It is taken from the nursery rhyme:

Nick knack paddy-whack give a dog a bone, this old man came rolling home.


I think how you understand this idiom relies heavily on context. Here is YouTube link where the idiom is explained as meaning something very different (as an act of kindness).
